# classA has no attribute `camera` error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, manim

I am working with a large Python library with a lot of files and Classes. I tried to create my own class to prevent code duplication. Here is a basic overview of all the classes.

```
# The Scene Class
class Scene(Container):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Container.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        // Set some attribute values including...
        self.camera = self.camera_class(**self.camera_config)

# The Camera Class
class MovingCamera(Camera):
     def __init__(self,  frame=None, **kwargs):
         // Set up values some values and then...
         Camera.__init__(self, **kwargs)

# The MovingCameraScene Class
from manimlib.camera.moving_camera import MovingCamera
from manimlib.scene.scene import Scene

class MovingCameraScene(Scene):
      CONFIG = {
          "camera_class": MovingCamera
      }

      def setup(self):
        Scene.setup(self)
        assert(isinstance(self.camera, MovingCamera))
        self.camera_frame = self.camera.frame
        return self

      // More code. There is no __init()__ method in this class.

# My Custom Class the Inherits MovingCamera Scene
class Something(MovingCameraScene):
      
      CONFIG = {
          "alpha": "beta"
      }

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           self.texts = []

      def common_method(self):
            
            texts = self.texts

            for i in texts:
                  // Manipulates Boxes

# My Final Class that Inherits Previous Class
class classA(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         texts = self.texts

         texts.append('Apple')
         .
         .
         .
         .
         self.common_method()

# This is another class that inherits `MovingCameraScene`
class classB(MovingCameraScene):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         texts = []

         texts.append('Apple')
         .
         .
         .
         .
         // More code that was in `common_method` of `Something` but directly pasted here.
```

There are many more classes but hopefully this should be enough.

I get the following error when I try to use my own class (`Something`) as parent of `classA`:

```
'classA' object has no attribute 'camera'
```

I don't get this error when using `classB` which directly inherits from `MovingCameraScene`.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `Something.__init__()` needs to call the parent class `__init__()`

Comment: Thanks @TomDalton but there is no `__init__()` in `MovingCameraScene`. :)

Comment: That's fine - the `__init__` of the parent of `MovingCameraScene` will be implicitly called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not call the super constructor in `Something`:

```py
class Something(MovingCameraScene):
      
      CONFIG = {
          "alpha": "beta"
      }

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(**kwargs)
           self.texts = []
```

Comment: Thanks @qumarana. :) I have two questions. 1. `MovingCameraScene` does not have an `__init()__` function. How does it work without calling its own super constructor? 2. Why does `classB` work without any error when it also inherits `MovingCameraScene` but does not call `__init()__` anywhere.

Comment: All the `__init__()` methods are just ordinary methods and can be overridden by derived classes, but if not they are inherited. The `super().__init__()` you see above calls the next `__init__()` upwards in the inheritance tree.

Comment: So `MovingCameraScene` inherits `__init()__` from `Camera` and works properly. classB also does not define its own `__init()__` function so it also inherits its own to work properly. However, I have defined my own `__init()__` for `classA` so it has been overridden and I need to call `__init()__` of its super constructor for it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks @quamrana. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: I think so, but your posting shows neither `classA`, not `classB` having their own `__init__()`.

Comment: I meant to say class `Something`. :)